# duplicate prestashop customer account multiple database php / sql / symfony

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, symfony, prestashop

I've a question for my personal project. I've two websites prestashop 1.7.7.x (two databases). I'cant active multisite on this shop this functionnality is instable

I search how to duplicate customers accounts avaibles in ps_customer.

I don't want to synchronize the database. When a customer registers on site A I want to insert the customer account on SITE B and vice versa.

My first idea :

- Make a php script automaticaly run with CRON TASK, this script check on db1 every account with condionnaly email and compare with db2 if not email found, I insert the data.

I've a problem with my sql query : (many many data returned,
a cause of the Cartesian product)

```
select db1.ps_customer.email from db1.ps_customer, db2.ps_customer where db1.ps_customer.email!=db2.ps_customer.email;
```

If you have any suggestions or information that could help me. Thank you very much.

Have a nice day,

Comment: You know it's 2021 right? The explicit ANSI-92 JOIN syntax has been around for 29 years; why are you *still* using that 1980's implicit join syntax?

Comment: Maybe simplify things. 
When a user registers in one site, search by unique field (email?) at the other site.  If does not exist then add.
No need for a cron task or complicated queries...

Answer (score 0):

The "Prestashop way" to handle this is by creating a module that you will install in both sites connected to the customer registration hook (**actionCustomerAccountAdd**) that "invokes" the prestashop API webservice on the other website , so when a customer succesfully register the hook is fired and customer with the same data is created on the other side.

You should start here : https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/

And here more details about webservice : https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/webservice/

Remember that both sites must share the same **cookie_key** in the configuration file otherwise the hashed passwords from site A will not work on  site B and vice versa.